# How to add collate to laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I need to run a query having `collate utf8_bin` like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field`='value' collate utf8_bin;
```

This is strictly for an admin script and I don't want to update the table charset itself, just for the particular query.

Can I do this using the Eloquent ORM or do I need to write this query out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can configure MySQL driver to use one:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

You can create a different connection for your particular query:

```
'mysql-collation' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => '<your collation>',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

And use that connection on your query:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql-collation')->select(...);
```

**EDIT:**

On a Model, you probably will be able to set a connection this way:

```
$posts = new Word;
$posts->setConnection('mysql-collation');
$posts->where(...);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this on a model:  `Word::connection('mysql-collation')->where()...`?  If I do: `DB:connection('mysql-collation')->table()...`, it doesn't let me use `->save()` later on the object returned.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it this way if it solves your problem:

```
SomeModel::whereField($value)->orderByRaw("name COLLATE utf8_bin ASC")->get();
```

Comment: This worked for me.  One issue I had is that I needed to have the collation in double quotes or else I was getting an error.  Mine looks like this: `->orderByRaw('name COLLATE "C" ASC');`.  Otherwise, I was getting this error: `Undefined object: 7 ERROR:  collation "c" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist`

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to apply this to the values in the WHERE clause:

```php
$value = "àBc123";
$query->whereRaw('field_name COLLATE utf8mb4_bin = (?)', $value);
```

- This query is both **case sensitive** and **accent sensitive**.
- Replace `utf8mb4_bin` with whatever collation makes sense on your system (eg. `utf8_bin`).
- Using `(?)` should utilize Laravel's query sanitization.

---

For **accent sensitive** but **NOT** case sensitive:

```php
$value = "àBc123";
$query->whereRaw('LOWER(field_name) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin = (?)', strtolower($value));
```