# Sort collection by utf-8 characters laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to sort name of provinces in VietNam by utf-8 characters.

**My Code**

```php
$provinces = Location::orderBy('name', 'ASC')
    ->whereNull('parent_id')->where('type', '1')
    ->pluck('name', 'id')
    ->toArray();

dd($provinces);
```

**Result**

```php
array:5 [
  "06" => "Bắc Kạn"
  92 => "Cần Thơ"
  15 => "Yên Bái"
  11 => "Điện Biên"
  48 => "Đà Nẵng"
]
```

**Expect**

```php
array:5 [
  "06" => "Bắc Kạn"
  92 => "Cần Thơ"
  11 => "Điện Biên"
  48 => "Đà Nẵng"
  15 => "Yên Bái"
]
```

Please help me.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that you need to sort according to the viet collation, soooo

```php
$arr = [
   6 => "Bắc Kạn",
  92 => "Cần Thơ",
  15 => "Yên Bái",
  11 => "Điện Biên",
  48 => "Đà Nẵng"
];

$c = new Collator('vi_VN');
$c->sort($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "Bắc Kạn"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "Cần Thơ"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "Đà Nẵng"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "Điện Biên"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "Yên Bái"
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/collator.sort.php

**Edit:** Come to think of it, if all the data in the DB is Vietnamese you should change to a viet collation like `utf8mb4_vi_0900_ai_ci` so that your DB consistently orders things across the board. The following will list all available collations on your DB:

```sql
SHOW COLLATION WHERE Charset = 'utf8mb4';
```

Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html

Also: [How to add collate to laravel query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19518523/1064767)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. But I received an error message: `Class 'App\Collator' not found`. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

you could do it using [php iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv)

you can omit (orderBy here):

```
$provinces = Location::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->whereNull('parent_id')->where('type', '1')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();



 $sorted = array_values(Arr::sort($array, function ($value) {
            return iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $value);
        }));
```

see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50990622/10573560